# Calling iloc() with a boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, boolean, slice

I am experimenting with the iloc method.  According to the documentation a boolean array is an allowed input.

The way I understand this, is that if I have a boolean array idx with values F, T, T, T and I pass it as input as follows: df.iloc(: , idx) then I will get the 2nd, 3d and 4th column of df (assume that df has 4 columns).

I tried to implement this but I run into errors.

As an example I have a dataframe df

```
            col1    col2    col3    col4
      0      1       2        3       4
      1      5       6        7       8
```

I also have a Pandas boolean Series:

```
     idx = pd.Series(['False', 'True', 'True', 'True'])
```

I convert the boolean Series to a boolean np.array:

```
    idx = idx.values
```

Then I pass it to iloc

```
    df.iloc[: , idx]
```

I get the error message:

```
    IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

which I do not understand since the dataframe has 4 columns and I pass 4 boolean values.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: change the string values in `idx` with boolean values: `pd.Series([False, True, True, True])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing iloc a series of strings and not a series of booleans. You did not create a boolean array and instead created a Series of strings with values 'True' and 'False'.

Change this

```
idx = pd.Series(['False', 'True', 'True', 'True'])
```

To this

```
idx = pd.Series([False, True, True, True])
```

And you will also have to use the values of the Series you created as I am getting a `NotImplemented` error with `df.iloc[:, idx]`

So use this instead:

```
df.iloc[:, idx.values]
```

Comment: More precisely - `df.iloc[: , pd.eval(idx)]`

Comment: Excellent!  According to the documentation the values() method converts a Series to an np array.  Since the documentation indicates that we must pass as input a boolean array it makes sense to convert idx to an np.array and pass it as idx.values.  I tried it and worked.  Why Nickil says that we need instead pd.eval(idx)?